# How to string 3 tables to get filter table

Tags: google-sheets

EDIT:

EDIT: I used this formula
=UNIQUE(FILTER({A2:A10, B2:B10, J2:J10}, (C2:C10=A20) * (J2:J10=B20)))

works, but say I select in dropdowns Agent Ike and Status Outreach. It shows an ID that is not in the blue table (ID 2011)

I have 3 tables:

Yellow = Product ID, Product, Agent assigned to the product

Green = Product ID, Comment about product, Date the Comment was made

Blue = Product ID, Status of the product, Start date of status, End date of status

[image]

below I have drop down to select agent (cell a20) and status (b20). I want the headers below that to populate filtered data to show data based on those three tables above. in cell a22 I'd expect it to search the three tables and find column C = Mike and look at column J = Negotiating to populate the data to find the ID, Product, Status that match those two dropdowns.

Calc:

```
=unique(filter({A2:A8,B2:B8,J2:J6},C2:C8=A20,J2:J6=B20))
```

This is what I would expect to populate if the calc worked:

[image]

Here is the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13o5d1AhslmYP3BcO1U16DxkyoCxo44rt7wgOKcq-PeE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A2:B8,C2:C8=A20,INDEX(COUNTIFS(FILTER(I2:I6,J2:J6=B20),A2:A8))>0),y,TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT(B20&"|",ROWS(x)),"|")),HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]